# how to call function variable into the other function parameter or argument?

Tags: javascript

I want to insert total_dist value in the calculatePrice parameter. How can i call total_dist in the total_dist function into calcautePrice total_dist paramter.

```
 function total_dist(){

      total_dist = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(origin_lat,origin_lng,pickup_lat,pickup_lng);
      return total_dist;
    }


    function calculatePrice(base_cost, base_dist, additional_cost, additional_dist, total_dist) {  
      if (total_dist > base_dist) {
        var dist_diff = total_dist - base_dist;
        var time = Math.ceil(dist_diff / additional_dist);
        return (time * additional_cost) + base_cost;
      }else {
        return base_cost;
      }
    }
```

Thanks you so much.

Comment: I dont understand your question ..why do you want do this

Comment: i got it bro.Thanks u for your help to think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first obtain the return value of `total_dist()` and  pass the same value as argument to `calculatePrice()` like this,

```
var td=total_dist();
calculatePrice(base_cost, base_dist, additional_cost, additional_dist, td)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke it: `if (total_dist() > base_dist)` and so on.

You have a bigger problem in which you're implicitly declaring `total_dist` inside a function called `total_dist` so you're going to have reference issues. Do this instead:

```
function total_dist(){
    return getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(origin_lat, origin_lng, pickup_lat, pickup_lng);
}
```

Comment: thanks bro,Now i got the ans by BalaYesu Chilakalapudi

Answer (score 0):

Store the value returned by total_dist in a variable, say _t_dist. Now use this variable whereever you need. Below is the modified code.

```
function total_dist(){

  total_dist = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(origin_lat,origin_lng,pickup_lat,pickup_lng);
  return total_dist;
}


function calculatePrice(base_cost, base_dist, additional_cost, additional_dist, total_dist) {
   var _t_dist = total_dist ();
  if (_t_dist > base_dist) {
    var dist_diff = _t_dist - base_dist;
    var time = Math.ceil(dist_diff / additional_dist);
    return (time * additional_cost) + base_cost;
  }else {
    return base_cost;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you but i just need the function parameter value.but now fix ok